# Where is the site.css file located for Identity?

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have an asp.net core 2.1 MVC application. I have ran the Scaffold Identity which has generated all the HTML and models used. I can't however find the css file that identity is using for its layouts?

In chrome developer tools it tells me site.css is being loaded from `/Identity/css/site.css` and bootstrap is being loaded from `/Identity/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css`. These files don't seem to exist anywhere in my project. Am I missing something?

It's not using the `site.css` file that's located in `wwwroot/css`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Identity default UI is a Razor Class Library. The static resources are being embedded and loaded from the library. Specifically, the Static Files middleware is loading up the embedded resources as if they were on the filesystem, using a `ManifestEmbeddedFileProvider`.

Long and short, you can override those by simply creating files in the same location in your project. Then, your project's versions will take over. Unfortunately, the scaffold doesn't provide a way to scaffold static resources as well. However, you can simply view the source in your browser and then copy that into your project's version of the file.

You can also view the [source of the RCL here](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/tree/2.1.3/src/UI). That way you can reference whatever code you need, without even needing the scaffold. Anything you add to your own project overrides what's coming from the RCL.

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thanks for the heads up about just overriding what I need to as well!

Comment: I'm getting an error in ASP .NET Core 5:

`The static web asset 'C:\Users\<user>\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.ui\5.0.10\build\..\staticwebassets\V4\css\site.css' has a conflicting web root path '/wwwroot/Identity/css/site.css' with the project file 'wwwroot\Identity\css\site.css'.`

Somehow overriding doesn't work anymore. Are there any other workarounds?

Comment: To circumvent this problem you can create your own folder, e.g. "OwnIdentity\css" and put a site.css into that folder. In _Layout.cshtml you can then change the reference to the stylesheet from href="~/Identity/css/site.css" into href="~/OwnIdentity/css/site.css" -> and then the compiler will not complain.