# Why does Scaffolding Identity for .NET Core 3.1 and .NET 5 in Visual Studio 2019 16.9.5 fail?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I'm trying to generate Identity Account\Login and Account\Register pages in a new project. I've tried both .NET Core 3.1 and .NET 5; in both cases, even when it's a new project, I receive the following error message:

[image]

An incredibly helpful error message, as you can tell. Does anybody know what can cause this with .NET Core 3.1 or .NET 5 projects and how to fix it? I've got VS2019 v16.9.5 installed, Microsoft's IdentityServer v.5.0.6, EntityFrameworkCore v.5.0.6, Identity.UI v5.0.6, and CodeGeneration.Design v.5.0.2 all installed for my .NET 5 project, and whatever the default versions of those packages for the new .NET Core 3.1 project. Both projects fail to correctly scaffold the needed files.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found a workaround for this error by using the dotnet CLI outside of Visual Studio to execute the scaffolding tool.
The following steps use the aspnet-codegenerator tool to scaffold the full Identity pages area into your .Net Core 5 app.

1.Close Visual Studio.

2.Open a command prompt and change directories to the project location.

3.Make sure the aspnet-codegenerator tool is installed on your machine by executing this command:

`dotnet tool install -g dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator`

4.Add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design package to the project if it does not already exist in your project.

`Install-Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design`

5.Run the following command where **YourAppName.Models.ApplicationDbContext** is the namespace to your DbContext:

`dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity -dc YourAppName.Models.ApplicationDbContext`

If the command completed without errors that should have fixed the “There was an error running the selected code generator” issue and created the necessary Identity Pages under Areas/Identity/Pages.

[image]

dotnet aspnet-codegenerator also has the ability to scaffold only specific files versus all the Identity files if you don’t need the full set by passing in the -files parameter followed by the files you want to create.

`dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity -dc MyApp.Models.ApplicationDbContext –files “Account.Register;Account.Login;Account.Logout”`

Further you need to add following packages in project
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design

Comment: I'm testing this answer out and looking into @JamieD77's answer as well. I'd like to use .NET 5, although his answer sounds sensible for .NET Core 3.1. I tested your answer in a new .NET 5 project and it's looking good. I'm wondering if your answer here has anything to do with what's causing the issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67498016/why-will-the-aspnetcore-identity-scaffolding-not-load-its-associated-css-and-js

Comment: I get the "Scaffolding Identity is not supported for web applications with minimal APIs for hosting and routing." error again ...

Answer (score 4):

Following up on JamieD77's answer, if you have this issue on .net 5, simply downgrade `Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI` to version 5.0.0. The scaffold will now work.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Closing the project and deleting the bin and obj folders worked in my case.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this yesterday.

What I had to do was install version 3.1.13 of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer` and then `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI` and after that, the scaffolding worked in VS2019

All of my AspCoreNet packages were set to 3.1.15 previously.

Comment: I was facing the same problem from last one day , search every page on internet but Only yours's solution works!  by downgrading to 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI
to  3.1.13

Answer (score 0):

For me it solved when update the entity framework core to the latest version

Answer (score 0):

For dotnet 6 just upgrade all identity and ef core related libraries to version 6.x.x. Also the database ef core libraries.