# "Invalid login" when logging into my new Razor Pages app

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, razor-pages

I created a new Razor Pages app. I ran that app and created an account. (A confirmation email was sent, which I clicked.) And that account was working. But today, I'm unable to log in.

> Invalid login attempt.

Even though I believe I remember the password, I tried the Forgot Password feature. No email was sent.

I've reviewed my account in the database. Here are the values of the relevant columns from the *AspNetUsers* table:

- `EmailConfirmed`: `True`
- `LockoutEnd`: `NULL`
- `AccessFailedCount`: `0`

Next, I tried to scaffold the Login and Forgot Password so I could debug the code. But this failed. (You can see my post about this issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/Scaffolding/issues/1601).)

So at this point, I'm blocked. Can anyone else suggest other things I might try to resolve this issue? What other things can cause this behavior?

Comment: Can you reproduce this with a new scaffold? This seems like it might have just been a weird one time bug with the original scaffold.

Comment: @Deckerz: Well, it is a new project/scaffolding. The thing is, it was working fine, but then stopped working. So my guess is the code works as designed, but there's a problem and it won't tell me the problem out of security concerns.

Answer (score 0):

`SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync` requires Username and Password, not an Email and Password so if you have Username same as Email it will work with you else it won't work.so makesure  make `UserName` value = `Email`.

Also, It's better to query the user by awaiting `_userManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email)` Then pass this user to the `PasswordSignInAsync` make sure `FindByEmailAsync`to check if the user with the given name exists something Like this:-

```
var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email);
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
```

I think it will help to resolve your issue.

Comment: I think your answer is off track in a few ways here. First of all, the default identity setup with Razor Pages is to use the email as the username. The login prompt even says *Email*. So I don't know why you would think it's different. Second, I'm using identity code generated by Visual Studio. So, if it's wrong, then Microsoft is wrong. Moreover, as I explained in my question, I cannot change the code because I cannot scaffold it. The code remains internal to the .NET libraries.

Comment: @JonathanWood I actually have not noticed you are using the default identity. So you have a scaffolding problem. here is my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67512332/why-does-scaffolding-identity-for-net-core-3-1-and-net-5-in-visual-studio-2019/67513449#67513449 please check my answer and try to solve your scaffolding problem.

Answer (score 0):

now you check are you set UserName value = Email. or no
beacuse in asp.net core identity by default use user name for login

Comment: As mentioned elsewhere in this question, the default is to use the email as the username.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar kind of situation, in my case security stamp value of the user recored in db table had get deleted somehow.

Also check whether username column has the sama value as Email column, if you use email as the username.

If you use scaffolded identity by default username column repeats the email value.

Comment: What security stamp are you referring to (table and column)?

Comment: In the aspnet users table, there is a column named securitystamp

Comment: The `AspNetUsers.SecurityStamp` column is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

"Invalid login attempt" typically means either username or password is incorrect. Most likely password.

I found I cannot receive any email so resetting password by email is a not an option in the default scaffolded project.

Here is a way to reset the password: Register a new user(remember the password:-) ), go to the database and copy the passwordhash from new user and apply it to the user you have problem with and see if it logs with the new password in now.

**Updates**

The real reason of "Invalid login attempt" isn't revealed to the user but it is logged. So if you run the application in debug mode, it will capture the reason. E.g. if I type in wrong password, I will get following in the output console:

warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager[0]

```
  Invalid password for user.
```

warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager[2]

```
  User failed to provide the correct password.
```

**Update : login flow when you get "Invalid login attempt"(Razor page)**

https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/master/src/UI/Areas/Identity/Pages/V4/Account/Login.cshtml.cs

You get "Invalid login attemp" because _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync method return SignResult.Failed or SignInResult.NotAllowed

```
public override async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null){
   ....
          ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
}
```

https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/master/src/Identity/SignInManager.cs

You get  SignInResult.Failed with no logging if user cannot be found

```
public virtual async Task<SignInResult> PasswordSignInAsync(string userName, string password,
            bool isPersistent, bool lockoutOnFailure)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);
            if (user == null)
            {

                return SignInResult.Failed;
            }

            return await PasswordSignInAsync(user, password, isPersistent, lockoutOnFailure);
        }
```

This method calls bellow method which only returns error, SignInResult.Success or put out a log message:

```
public virtual async Task<SignInResult> CheckPasswordSignInAsync(TUser user, string password, bool lockoutOnFailure)
        {
            if (user == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(user));
            }

            var error = await PreSignInCheck(user);
            if (error != null)
            {
                return error;
            }

            if (await UserManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, password))
            {
                var alwaysLockout = AppContext.TryGetSwitch("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.CheckPasswordSignInAlwaysResetLockoutOnSuccess", out var enabled) && enabled;
                // Only reset the lockout when TFA is not enabled when not in quirks mode
                if (alwaysLockout || !await IsTfaEnabled(user))
                {
                    await ResetLockout(user);
                }

                return SignInResult.Success;
            }
            Logger.LogWarning(2, "User {userId} failed to provide the correct password.", await UserManager.GetUserIdAsync(user));
```

PresigninCheck and CanSignUser deals with confirmation and lock and you will get a different message in UI other than "Invalid login attempt", and also has some logs:

```
protected virtual async Task<SignInResult> PreSignInCheck(TUser user)
        {
            if (!await CanSignInAsync(user))
            {
                return SignInResult.NotAllowed;
            }
            if (await IsLockedOut(user))
            {
                return await LockedOut(user);
            }
            return null;
        }
```

CanSignInAsync can return fasle which cause SignInResult.NotAllowed, but all with logging:

```
public virtual async Task<bool> CanSignInAsync(TUser user)
        {
            if (Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail && !(await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user)))
            {
                Logger.LogWarning(0, "User {userId} cannot sign in without a confirmed email.", await UserManager.GetUserIdAsync(user));
                return false;
            }
            if (Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber && !(await UserManager.IsPhoneNumberConfirmedAsync(user)))
            {
                Logger.LogWarning(1, "User {userId} cannot sign in without a confirmed phone number.", await UserManager.GetUserIdAsync(user));
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
```

Comment: FYI, my browser filled in the username and password because it remembered them. I didn't type them in when the problem started. Seems unlikely the browser would get them wrong. And the app IS able to send emails.

Comment: the stored password can be wrong if you typed wrong. There is only a few outcomes and you  have ruled out locked/confirmed. The source code is here https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/master/src/Identity/SignInManager.cs. I realized I am too assertive so I update my answer on how to confirm it.

Comment: But it worked when I typed it in, and it's been working fine when the browser filled it in for me until now. For these reasons, I'm confident it's the right password. And even if it wasn't, the Forgot Password would still work if everything else was okay. Also, I tried looking in the Ouput console but, with Razor Pages, it shows no related message.

Comment: If you get no logs it means the username is wrong and cannot be found in the db. Please see my update

Comment: I can see in the database that my username is right. What do you think I missed in your update?

Comment: I updated with more detail. basically this is not hugely complex code and should be relatively easy to  follow

Comment: I think the only way I'll solve this is if I can get the Identity scaffolding to work.

Comment: someone over there is trying to help you with this https://github.com/dotnet/Scaffolding/issues/1601

Comment: What do you mean? No one answered my last comment there.

Comment: to be fair he asked you to try something, and what is your response to that?

Comment: The only thing he asked me to do was try it again, which I did and reported on the results. I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: It will be kind if you can confirm the original problem is fixed after following his suggestion. You throw out next error message which has nothing to with it, and this one is very clear on where it goes wrong. You want someone's help to interprete the message?

Comment: My issue was that the scaffolding feature was unreliable and generally fails for me. Then I gave some errors I'm getting. When I tried it again, I got different errors. I'd be happy to confirm the original problems was fixed if in fact it was. But it was not. I'm simply getting a different error. I have no way to tell if the original error is fixed or I'm just running into trouble at a different point. But either way, the scaffolding feature still does not work. It's hard to see why you don't understand this. I don't know how else I can explain it to you.

Comment: you know how big the community/user base is toward this scaffolding feature?(or any sort of popular technologies).

Answer (score 0):

Please try to log in from a different machine with a different internet connection - this is an issue I had too  - I solved it by using a different computer with the same password & username

Comment: The website is running locally on my computer. And a different internet connection could never produce the result that I'm seeing.